# Unable to record for file path 'C:\....\MyProject.CAB' on every setup project in VS

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

I'm trying to build my setup project in VS but, suddendly, it doesn't work anymore.

I don't know what I have done, or what I do (except adding a new file), but i get this error :

***ERROR: Unable to create record for file path 'C:...\Debug\SOFIN.CAB' 'Le chemin d’accès spécifié n’est pas valide.'***

I have triple check the given path and it exist but I don't why it doesn't want to do it thing.

Edit :

This append to me on every setup project in visual studio and also on two different PC. Is it visual studio or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is too heavy for .CAB file.
File format limitation (cannot be bigger than 2GB) create an error while building the setup.

Solution is don't use **Package As : In Setup File** but **Package As : As loose uncompressed files**